# Recursion not working

Tags: java, recursion

I'm wanted to make arrays with the digits 0-6 where the digits are evenly distributed. To find every possible solution, I wanted to use Recursion to place a digit that can be placed there and move on to the next position. But when I run it with Eclipse. It will go through once and then back to the first call and continue with the for-loop, but without calling the method again.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Search {
int WIDTH = 8;
int HEIGHT = 7;

boolean hasDistroStopped = false;
boolean hasSolveStopped  = false;
boolean hasUniqueStopped = false;

public LinkedList<String> fDistro = new LinkedList<String>();
//public LinkedList<String> fSolve  = new LinkedList<String>();
//public LinkedList<String> fUnique = new LinkedList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    Search a = new Search();

    FindDistro findDistro = a.new FindDistro();
    //FindSolve findSolve = a.new FindSolve();
    //FindUnique findUnique = a.new FindUnique();

    findDistro.start();
    //findSolve.start();
    //findUnique.start();
}

public class FindDistro extends Thread{
    long start;
    int[] field = new int[WIDTH*HEIGHT];
    int[] distro = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    public FindDistro(){}

    public void run(){
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        findFieldsRecursive(field,distro,0);

        synchronized(fDistro){
            System.out.println("Found " + fDistro.size() + " fields in " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)/1000) + "s.");
            hasDistroStopped = true;
        }
    }
    /**
     * This method evenly populates recursively the field with numbers and allows every field to be
     * found without the danger of invalid ones.
     * @param f The current field
     * @param d The current distribution of numbers
     * @param pos The current position in the field. Has to be zero to start the recursion properly.
     */
    public void findFieldsRecursive(int[] f, int[] d, int pos){
        // Test if we finished the field
        if (pos == f.length){
            String a = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
                a += Integer.toString(f[i]);
            }
            synchronized(fDistro){
                fDistro.add(a);
            }
            return;
        }

        //Test for the numbers
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++){
            if(d[i] != WIDTH){
                f[i] = i;
                d[i]++;
                findFieldsRecursive(f,d,pos + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So have you stepped through the code in a debugger? If so, did you find where you'd *expect* it to recurse, but it didn't?

Comment: It is not that folks here are mean but most of times running the debugger takes less time to learn than posting, formatting, and waiting for an answer. And you have the benefit of avoiding cranky answers/comments

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry. I never have actually used a debugger. But using it revealed that the arrays f and d do not stay on the supposed states while going down the call stack. I forgot to remove the added value on d again. Now it works properly. But what i don't get is that the debugger shows me f with the numbers I have assigned to it further up the call stack, but there should be nothing, since in java you pass a copy as parameter to a method or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is working:

[image]

Your algorithm might not be though. It's not really clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.